# How do i get a hourly report from sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Is there any way to get a datetime based report from MySql?

I have a table and one of the fields is a timestamp, and I want to grab the amount of records in certain portion of time (ex. between 2017-09-19 13:00:01 and 2017-09-19 14:00:00, total amount X).

Comment: Not without writing something, I'm guessing.

Comment: Usually involves some SQL code. What have you tried?

Comment: you need to write some sql code

Comment: Please share the code you attempted

Comment: Agreed with all of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to get records from a table between two values use BETWEEN, for example:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE hour BETWEEN '2017-09-01 10:00:00' AND '2017-09-01 11:00:00'`

Comment: I was asking to get write a query to get this records between timestamps, but one of my coworkers told me to use one query like this 
SELECT * FROM
table
WHERE HOUR(time_stamp) > '12:00:00' AND HOUR(time_stamp) < '13:00:00'

Comment: I edited my answer after your comment, hope this helps. COUNT gives you the number of records rather than returning the actual records. Using one > and one < conditional works, but BETWEEN is often more clear.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2017-09-19 13:00:00' and '2017-09-19 13:59:59';
```